# How can I find [Call MyFunction] in Visual Studio 2013 but exclude ['Call MyFunction]

Tags: regex, search, visual-studio-2013

I have looked at the regular expression examples in VS 2013 but don't know how to return just the non-commented out calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Using Regular Expressions in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx) (changed since VS2010)

As far as I know, the `Call` statement can only appear at the beginning of a line, so this should do:

```
^\s*Call\s+MyFunction
```

That is: beginning of line, followed by optional spaces, then Call.

In general, to write "do not match anything following the quote character", you can replace the space with "any non-quote character", i.e. `[^']`:

```
^[^']*TextToFind
```

Although this would skip lines that are not necessarily commented, such as:

```
quoted = "'" + TextToFind + "'"
```

If this is a VB.NET solution and you are just trying to navigate your code, you should be able to just right-click `MyFunction` and click "Find All References".

Comment: Thank you @nmclean for your help. That solved the problem. Unfortunately it's Classic ASP so haven't got the luxury of clicking "Find All References".